# How to log JSP error to backend

Tags: jsp

When an error occured in my jsp, it will be redirected to an error page using errorPage = error.jsp, in which error.jsp set with isErrorPage = true directive, so how can i log the error message from error.jsp to backend database ?

Is it workable and good practice to write javascript ajax in the jsp error page which use ajax post method in $(document).ready to call controller REST method to update database ?

Appreciate the advice as i can't find it thru internet after searching hours.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have considered to use scriptlets to retrieve the request parameters and exception stack-trace, then input to custom tag library for triggering to backend.  Is it a good practice ?  Would appreciate if any expert here can provide advice.  Thanks again